# No valid parser available(Play Framework) sbt[error]

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I am stuck in Deployment of Play framework application using an sbt command i.e "`sbt '-Dsbt.global.base=/opt/.sbt/0.13.13 -Dsbt.ivy.home=/opt/.ivy2 -Dsbt.boot.directory=/opt/.sbt/boot -Dsbt.repository.config=/opt/.sbt/repositories' ‘start -Dconfig.resource=test_application.conf’`". It always shows me an error i.e `No valid parser available` . I need help on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have wrong quotes. Try to change

```
‘start -Dconfig.resource=test_application.conf’
```

to

```
'start -Dconfig.resource=test_application.conf'
```